# 'list' object has no attribute, why is that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to pass in a list of items through a class parameter and call the method `display_flavors` to print the list. But I am receiving a `list object has no attribute error`.

I have rewritten the code that works but I want to rewrite the code to pass in a list instead of calling the method and passing through the list argument. Is it possible?

```py
# Python script Idea to be implemented which has an error
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):  # Inherits the Parent Class "Restaurant"
    """Attempt to represent an Ice Cream Stand"""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_name, flavors):
        """Initialize the attributes of an Ice Cream Stand"""
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_name) 
        self.flavors = flavors

    def display_flavors(self):
        """Print all the flavors the Ice Cream Stand offers"""
        print("These are flavors offered in this Ice Cream Stand:")
        for flavor in self.flavors:
            print(flavor.title())

list_of_flavors = ["chocolate", "strawberry", "banana"]
restaurant1 = IceCreamStand("Dairy King", "Dairy and Ice Cream", list_of_flavors)
restaurant1.flavors.display_flavors()
```

========================================================================
Rewritten code that works

```py
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):  # Inherits Parent Class "Restaurant"
     """Attempt to represent an Ice Cream Stand"""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_name):
        """Initialize the attributes of an Ice Cream Stand"""
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_name)

    def display_flavors(self, flavors):
        """Print all the flavors the Ice Cream Stand offers"""
        print("These are flavors offered in this Ice Cream Stand:")
        for flavor in flavors:
            print(flavor.title())

list_of_flavors = ["chocolate", "strawberry", "banana"]
restaurant1 = IceCreamStand("Dairy King", "Dairy and Ice Cream")
restaurant1.display_flavors(list_of_flavors)
```

========================================================================

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'display_flavors'
```

Comment: The last line of your first code should be just `restaurant1.display_flavors()`.

Comment: `restaurant1.flavors` is a list, so when you call `restaurant1.flavors.display_flavors() `, you are trying to call the method `.display_flavors()` of that list, which doesn't exist.

Comment: `restaurant1.flavors` is a list. Python lists don't have any attribute in the name `display_flavors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a dot operator to call a function, you're generally calling that function with its first argument being the thing *before* the dot operator. This is why we include `self` when we're writing methods inside a class, like `display_flavors`.

When you do

```
restaurant1.flavors.display_flavors()
```

then Python tries to call the method `display_flavors()` on the object `restaurant1.flavors`, with no other arguments. However, `restaurant1.flavors` is a list, and as a result doesn't have a method called `display_flowers()`. Hence your `AttributeError`.

Meanwhile, when you do

```
restaurant1.display_flavors(list_of_flavors)
```

you're calling the method `display_flavors()` on `restaurant1` - which is an `IceCreamStand`, and which *does* have a method called that. Said method is given two arguments: `restaurant1` (as `self`), and `list_of_flavors`.

So, doing `restaurant1.display_flavors()` instead of `restaurant1.flavors.display_flavors()` in your first example should work.

Answer (score 1):

It now works!! Thanks guys for the clarification was stuck forever with that error

```py
# Corrected Script
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):  # Inherits the attributes from Parent Class "Restaurant"
    """Attempt to represent an Ice Cream Stand"""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_name, flavors):
        """Initialize the attributes of an Ice Cream Stand"""
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_name)
        self.flavors = flavors

    def display_flavors(self):
        """Print all the flavors the Ice Cream Stand offers"""
        print("These are flavors offered in this Ice Cream Stand:")
        for flavor in self.flavors:
            print(flavor.title())


list_of_flavors = ["chocolate", "strawberry", "banana"]
restaurant1 = IceCreamStand("Dairy King", "Dairy and Ice Cream", list_of_flavors)
restaurant1.display_flavors()  # <<< Here is the correction
```

Output:

```
    These are flavors offered in this Ice Cream Stand:
    Chocolate
    Strawberry
    Banana
```